# Need to reduce the number of recursive calls in this function

Tags: python, string, recursion

The problem is given a string S and an integer k<len(S) we need to find the highest string in dictionary order with any k characters removed but maintaining relative ordering of string.

This is what I have so far:

```
def allPossibleCombinations(k,s,strings):
    if k == 0:
       
        strings.append(s)
        return strings
    
    for i in range(len(s)):
        new_str = s[:i]+s[i+1:]
        strings = allPossibleCombinations(k-1, new_str, strings)
        
    return strings

def stringReduction(k, s):
    strings = []
    combs = allPossibleCombinations(k,s, strings)
    return sorted(combs)[-1]
```

This is working for a few test cases but it says that I have too many recursive calls for other testcases. I don't know the testcases.

Comment: The right way for solving this is using *dynamic programming*.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started -

```py
from itertools import combinations

def all_possible_combinations(k = 0, s = ""):
  yield from combinations(s, len(s) - k)
```

Now for a given `k=2`, and `s="abcde"`, we show all combinations of `s` with `k` characters removed -

```py
for c in all_possible_combinations(2, "abcde"):
  print("".join(c))

# abc
# abd
# abe
# acd
# ace
# ade
# bcd
# bce
# bde
# cde
```

Answer (score 0):

> it says that I have too many recursive calls for other testcases

I'm surprised that it failed on recursive calls before it failed on taking too long to come up with an answer.  The recursion depth is the same as `k`, so `k` would have had to reach 1000 for default Python to choke on it.  However, your code takes 4 minutes to solve what appears to be a simple example:

```
print(stringReduction(8, "dermosynovitis"))
```

The amount of time is a function of `k` and string length.  The problem as I see it, recursively, is this code:

```
for i in range(len(s)):
    new_str = s[:i]+s[i+1:]
    strings = allPossibleCombinations(k-1, new_str, strings, depth + 1)
```

Once we've removed the first character say, and done all the combinations without it, there's nothing stopping the recursive call that drops out the second character from again removing the first character and trying all the combinations.  We're (re)testing too many strings!

The basic problem is that you need to *prune* (i.e. avoid) strings as you test, rather than generate *all* possibilties and test them.  If a candidate's first letter is less than that of the best string you've seen so far, no manipulation of the remaining characters in that candidate is going to improve it.